# Java JFrame Graphics Update

Tags: java, swing, graphics

I am playing around with graphics in Java using JFrames and am trying to completely understand when `Graphics` changes actually occur.

Let's say I have a timer running every second, and every second the graphics change.  The tick method, for example, will run every second...

```
public void tick(Graphics g) {
    g.fillRect(0,0,10,10);
    //Do Some Computations
    g.fillRect(0,0,someComputedWidth,someComputedHeight);
}
```

Are the graphics instantly updated on the computers display?  When the first `fillRect` method is called, is that rectangle instantly created?

I want to be able to draw all my graphics, and then make them have their effect at the same exact time.  I want the tick method to buffer all updates, and then execute them all at once.  How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To buffer your updates you can use BufferedImage:

```
@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
    BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(this.size.width, this.size.height, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
    Graphics bgr = image.getGraphics(); 
    for(Tile t : this.tiles){
        t.draw(bgr);
    }   
    super(bgr);
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
    bgr.dispose();      
    image = null;
}
```

I used this method in one of my school projects. It draws to an off-screen image and then draws the image to display.
With few drawable objects being drawn, and no, or little animation, updating directly to the display does not always have noticable effects, however with more complex tasks the image "flickers" and double buffering is a perfect cure for that.

Comment: Cool.  Whats the differnece between ` super.paintComponents(bgr);` and `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);`?  What does the `paintComponent()` usually do and where is it usually called from?

Comment: super.paintComponents(bgr) calls method up the inheritance tree. It draws and does all that's needed with swing components present in your panel. bgr is bufferedImage's graphics and that's where components are drawn. g draws to the display, in this case it draws bufferedImage, at x=0 y=0 (top left corner), null means there is no observer

Comment: Great! The term for this is double buffering?

Comment: Yes, there is also triple buffering if I remember correctly

Comment: Sounds trippy, I'll look into it.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Don't invoke super.paintComponents(). You should invoke super on the method you are overriding, which is super.paintComponent().

Comment: @HurricaneDevelopment, Swing is double buffered by default. There is no need to use a BufferedImage, especially when you create the BufferedImage in the paintComponent() method. You can just do you painting in the paintComponent() method. Think of a JTextPane. All the text in painted at once without the use of a BufferedImage.